# How do I follow a Google Group using an RSS reader?

Tags: rss, google-groups

I am the owner of a Google Group. I am using the new interface. The group is a public group and is available at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=&nomobile=true#!forum/sr-api.

I cannot find a way to subscribe to new posts using an RSS reader. I have done some googling and it seems that the new Google Groups does not support RSS feeds. Have anyone found a way to get an RSS feed from the new Google Groups?

Comment: For anyone who is having trouble with this but has not noticed the important key that Jacob provided, it is required that your group is a public group to get an RSS feed.

Comment: It seems things have changed a few days ago. On the "About" page there is no info about RSS feeds and the previous URLs stopped working. Do we have any new idea?

Comment: The current problem with GGroups and RSS is being discussed here: https://support.google.com/groups/thread/118690869/when-will-googlegroups-rss-feed-be-back-online?hl=en&msgid=118690869

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find it here:

https://groups.google.com/group/sr-api/about?noredirect

The link is currently missing from the About page in the new Group groups.

Comment: Please include a relevant snippet of the linked page that answers the question. Posting only links to external sites is discouraged on SE, to prevent link rot.

Comment: @pleinolijf http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69904/30592 did it for you

Answer (score 8):

Combining answers by [Rich Feit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/33390/30592) and [vishvAs vAsuki](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/41045/30592), the about page for your project is reached via

https://groups.google.com/group/sr-api/about?noredirect <sup>please replace `sr-api` with your group</sup>

This will lead to links like:

[**https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/sr-api/msgs/rss.xml?num=50**](https://groups.google.com/forum/feed/sr-api/msgs/rss.xml?num=50)<sup>(again, replacing `sr-api`)</sup>

from the about page, which anyway, as of 2014, looks like this:

[image: google groups about page screenshot part]

(the end)

Comment: This works in year 2019 month October

Comment: This has been silently Killed By Google™ around 2021-07-25. See https://support.google.com/groups/thread/118690869/when-will-googlegroups-rss-feed-be-back-online?hl=en